# Access specific column data with Android Xamarin SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

Am building a login activity in Xamarin Android and i have all the modules(libraries and files) plugged in and ready to go but i have a problem with retrieving a single object(Email Actually) from the table(it contains data already)...My code is explained below...

```
//The class that acts as a blueprint to the table is this one
class Person {
       [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get;}
        public string department { set; get; }
        public  string email { set; get; }
        public string password { set; get; }
            }
```

The file that handles the login logic

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity
    {
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Login button definition
  Button login=(Button)FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
     //Make the button raise login event on click
    login.Click +=Login;                                                                }
     }
//Button method for login
private void Login(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //Define location that the connection will use to create and store tables
string dbpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbpersons.db");
 //Define new connection to database using a connection string
  var conn=new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
    try{
          //Microsoft manual says this can access elements of a row using id parameter
        var stock = db.Get<Person>(5);
      // I need code that will let me access email from specific column in table
   }catch(SQLite.SQLiteException m){
    //Display exception in a toast
     Toast.MakeText(Application.Context,m.Message,ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }  
  }
}
```

I need that email to do comparisons with another value user will enter in ``EditText```

Comment: does the `Stock` table have an `email` column?  The class definition you posted was for `Person`, not `Stock`

Comment: @Jason, Good point editing in progress

Comment: Its good now,i just want code i will use to select email from from table nd compare it with value entered in EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are retrieving an object from the db, so to access a property of that object just use the property

```
var stock = db.Get<Person>(5);
// I need code that will let me access email from specific column in table
var email = stock.email;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked to retrieve email from id associated with that record, can you edit to do comparisons with value user entered in ```EditText```? if true launch a new activity(Dashboard Activity) and also passing email as intent extras to the dashboard class

Comment: How to check if SQLite query is returning true

Comment: Get returns an object, not a bool.

Comment: I managed to find this code to fetch an object and sql may return null but i have that handled and then i have code in that ```if else ``` logic and its ```object mail=connection.FindByQuery<Table>(query+parameters);```

Comment: if you have another question, you should post a new question

Comment: The parameter is ```edittext.Text```, SQLite query seems to return true when the query has the correct syntax but it seems when no object is found it returns ```null```, how do i deal with this?